Another question on the relation between integrals of differential forms and surface integrals
Consider the manifold $ M = \mathbb R^n $. Let $ \delta $ be the metric tensor and denote with $ \omega = \mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge \mathrm dx^n $ the Riemannian volume induced by $ \delta $. Moreover, choose an $ (n - 1) $-form $ \alpha $ defined on the whole space.
Some warmup
Write $ \alpha $ as
$$
\alpha = \sum_{j = 1}^n\alpha_j\,\mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\mathrm dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge \mathrm dx^n
$$
for some real functions $ \alpha_j $, and recall that

$ \alpha $ corresponds to a $ 1 $-form $ \operatorname{\star}\alpha $ that in the canonical basis expands to
$$
\star\alpha = \sum_{j = 1}^n(-1)^{n-j}\alpha_j\,\mathrm dx^j\,\text{;}
$$

$ \star\alpha $ (and ultimately $ \alpha $ itself) corresponds to the vector field $ \vec G $ whose components $ G^j $ are
$$
\vec G^j = (-1)^{n - j}\alpha_j
$$
under the metric correspondence between $ 1 $-forms and vectors.


The theorem I would like to prove [1]
Let $ S\subset \mathbb R^n $ be an embedded oriented hypersurface and denote with $ \iota\colon S\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^n $ the canonical inclusion.
Let $ (U,\phi) $, $ \phi = (x^1,\dots,x^n) $, be a chart on $ \mathbb R^3 $ adapted to $ S $ (i.e., suppose that $ U\cap S = \{z^n = 0\} $) and suppose that the induced chart on $ S $ is positive. We can always find such a chart since $ S $ is embedded by hypothesis. Suppose moreover that $ \alpha $ is compactly supported inside on $ U $. I want to show that
$$
\int_S\iota^*\alpha = \int_V\begin{vmatrix}G^1(\phi^{-1}(q)) & \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^1}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^1}{\partial q^n}(q) \\\vdots\\G^n(\phi^{-1}(q)) & \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^n}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^n}{\partial q^n}(q)\end{vmatrix}\,\lambda^{n - 1}(\mathrm dq) \label{formula}{\tag{$*$}}
$$
where the integral at RHS is the $ (n - 1) $-dimensional Lebesgue integral on the subset $ V = \phi(U\cap S) $ of the $ (n - 1) $-dimensional Euclidean space $ \mathbb R^{n - 1} $ of that scary-looking determinant (I'll denote with $ q $ the independent variable on $ V $; if the notation $ \int_V(\text{stuff})\,\lambda^{n - 1}(\mathrm dq) $ for Lebesgue integrals bothers you, pretend I have written $ \int_V(\text{stuff})\,\mathrm d\lambda^{n - 1}(q) $).
Some ancillary questions

First of all, let's assume that what I would like to prove is indeed true. Does a similar "computationally handy" formula holds in the case we substitute $ \mathbb R^n $ with some arbitrary Riemannian manifold?

The first thing one notices in the formula above is the presence of the derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^i}{\partial q^j}
$$
of the components of the chart $ \phi^{-1}\colon V\to U\cap S\subset \mathbb R^n $. We can not rely on such components in the abstract setting.

Is it true that
$$
\int_S\iota^*\alpha = \int_S\langle \vec G,\hat N\rangle\, \eta
$$
where $ \eta $ is the Riemannian volume induce on $ S $ by the receipt
$$
\eta = \hat N\mathop{\lrcorner} \omega
$$
and $\langle{{-},{-}}\rangle $ is the inner product induced by the metric?

I know that the RHS is equal to the integral of the divergence of $ \vec G $... but are
$$
\int_S\operatorname{div}\vec G\, \eta\qquad\text{and}\qquad \int_S\alpha
$$
the same thing?
What I've tried so far
One thing I noticed is that the determinant that appears on the RHS on $ \eqref{formula} $ looks like something that might arose form a contraction operation. I don't know if that's the case.
Anyway, I would try to express $ \alpha $ wiht respect to the volume form $ \eta $ like in
$$
\iota^*\alpha = f\,\eta\,\text{.}
$$
Then
$$
\int_S\iota^*\alpha = \int_V f(q)\lambda^{n - 1}(\mathrm dq)
$$
and if I show that
$$
f(q) = \begin{vmatrix}G^1(\phi^{-1}(q)) & \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^1}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^1}{\partial q^n}(q) \\\vdots\\G^n(\phi^{-1}(q)) & \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^n}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^n}{\partial q^n}(q)\end{vmatrix}
$$
I'm done. But I don't know how to carry out the calculation.
[1] There might be some sign error in the formula $ \eqref{formula} $ above. The reference I'm studying from instead of starting with a form $ \alpha $ expressed as
$$
\alpha = \sum_j\alpha_j\,\mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\mathrm dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dx^n
$$
expands $ \alpha $ as
$$
\alpha = \sum_j(-1)^{j + 1}\alpha_j\,\mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\mathrm dx^j}\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dx^n
$$
so that to obtain exactly
$$
G^j = a_j
$$
(forgetting about that annoying $ (-1)^{n - 1} $ factor). I dislike this way of telling the story since in my opinion makes unclear that we're using the identification
$$
\Omega^{n - 1}(\mathbb R^n)\cong \Omega^1(\mathbb R^n)
$$
provided by the Hodge star (but on the other hand I copied that formula with that huge determinant verbatim from the notes without changing anything because I was unsure how to make the appropriate changes... Let's hope it works! c: ).

I am not a big fan of working with submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so let's first start with the more elegant definitions for a general manifold and see where it takes us:
Let $S$ be a $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold and $\alpha\in\Omega^{n-1} (S)$ a top-degree form. If $(U,\Phi)$ is a chart of $S$, i.e. $U\subset S$ is open (in the topology of $S$) and
$$\Phi : U \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} \Phi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$$
is a homeomorphism, then the integral of $\alpha$ over $S\cap U$ is defined as
$$\int\limits_{S\cap U} \alpha := \int\limits_{\Phi(U)} (\Phi^{-1})^* \alpha,$$
provided the support of $\alpha$ is compact in $U$. In the coordinates on $S\cap U$ induced by $\Phi$, one can write $$\alpha = f(y)\cdot dy_1\wedge...\wedge dy_{n-1}.$$ Here, $d y_i := d\Phi_i : U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Since $y=\Phi^{-1}(x)$ for $x\in\Phi(U)$, this means that
$$(\Phi^{-1})^*\alpha = f(\Phi^{-1}(x)) \det(D\Phi^{-1})d x_1\wedge...\wedge d x_{n-1}$$ and so \begin{equation}\tag{1}\int\limits_{\Phi(U)}(\Phi^{-1})^*\alpha = \int\limits_{\Phi(U)} f(\Phi^{-1}(x)) \det (D\Phi^{-1}) d x_1\wedge...\wedge dx_{n-1},\end{equation}  The form $\det(D\Phi^{-1})dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_{n-1}$ is what one means by the "$(n-1)$-dim. volume element" denoted by $dS$ or $d\lambda^{n-1}(S)$.
Now, if one assumes $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S$ being a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold means that there exist charts $(U,\Psi)$ so that $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open, $$\Psi : U \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow}\Psi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^n,$$ as well as
$$\Psi(S\cap U) = (\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\})\cap\Psi(U).$$
In this case, writing $\Psi|_{S\cap U} = (\Phi,0)$, for $\Phi:S\cap U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, one has $$D\Psi|_{S\cap U}= \left(\begin{matrix} D\Phi \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times(n-1)},$$ and any $(n-1)$-form $\beta\subset\Omega^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\})$ can be seen as
$$\iota_{X_\beta} (dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n) = \det(X_\beta,\cdot,...,\cdot),$$
where $X_\beta =(0,...,g(x))$ if $\beta = (-1)^{n-1}g(x) dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_{n-1}$. Using (1), this means that for $\alpha\in \Omega^{n-1}(S)$, one has
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{S\cap U} \alpha &\overset{(1)}{=} \int\limits_{\Phi(S\cap U)}f(\Phi^{-1}(x_1,...,x_{n-1}) \det(D\Phi^{-1})dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_{n-1}\\
&= \int\limits_{\Phi(S\cap U)\times\{0\}} f(\Psi^{-1}(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0) \det(D\Phi^{-1})dx_1\wedge ...\wedge dx_n\\
&= \int\limits_{\Psi(U)} \det(X_f,D\Psi^{-1})d x\\
\end{align}
for $X_f = (0,...,(-1)^{n-1}f)$. Note that the last formula makes sense, since
$$(X_f,D\Psi^{-1})=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & D\Phi^{-1}\\ f &0 \end{matrix}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$ is a quadratic matrix. For a general chart $(U,\Psi)$ of $S$ so that $\Psi(U)$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional, but not necessarily contained in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$, one can still write $\alpha = \iota_{X_\alpha}\det$, but now for $X_\alpha = (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$. This yields the formula you were searching, i.e.
$$\int\limits_{S\cap U}\alpha = \int\limits_{\Psi(U)} \det(X_\alpha,D\Psi^{-1}) dx.$$

Could you please elaborate on why
$$
D\Psi = \begin{pmatrix}D\Phi\0\end{pmatrix},\text{?}
$$
What is $ \Phi $ in this context?

Moreover, the form $ \beta = g,\mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{-1}\in \Omega^{n - 1}(\mathbb R^{n - 1}\times {0}) $ shouldn't correspond to the form
$$
\color{red}{(-1)^{n + 1}}X_\beta\mathop{\lrcorner}{(\mathrm dx^1\wedge \dots\wedge \mathrm dx^n)}\in \Omega^{n - 1}(\mathbb R^n),\text{?}
$$

@GeometriaDifferenziale I fixed the first part $-$ one just writes $\Psi = (\Phi,0)$, using that $\Psi$ is a chart only in its first $(n-1)$ components.
For the second question: Yes, you are right.

Another (silly) question. Shouldn't the determinant $ \det(D\Phi^{-1}) $ be always equal to $ 1 $? In the expression $ \det(D\Phi^{-1}) $, $ D\Phi^{-1} $ stands for the Jacobian matrix of the function $ \Phi^{-1}\colon \mathbb R^n\to S $ with respect to the canonical basis of $ \mathbb R^{-1} $ and the basis $ { \partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n - 1}} $ induced on $ S $ by $ \Phi $, but shouldn't this matrix be just the identity matrix?

@GeometriaDifferenziale The basis ${\partial_1,...,\partial_{n-1}}$ on $S$ depends on the point $x\in S$. Think of how the tanget plane moves on the $2$-sphere when moving the base point. I updated my post to highlight that one looks at $\Psi|_{S\cap U}$, i.e. when differentiating, one has to take into account the constraint of always staying on $S$.

Let's take an "abstract" manifold $ S $. Pick an $ x\in S\cap U $ (for $ (U,\Phi) $ chart). Then $ \partial_\mu(x)\in \mathrm T_xS $ is by definition the vector $ \mathrm d(\Phi^{-1})x(e\mu) $, where $ e_\mu\in \mathrm T_{\Phi(x)}\mathbb R^{n - 1}\cong \mathbb R^{n - 1} $. So, suppose we want to compute the Jacobian matrix $ J $ of $ \Phi^{-1} $ at $ x $ with respect to the bases $ {e_\mu} $ and $ {\partial_\mu} $: we will have $ J = \mathrm{id} $. But $ J $ is exactly $ D\Phi^{-1}(x) $! What's wrong with this argument?

(Btw, I'm accepting your answer because apart from this little problem I'm completely OK with it)

I'll give myself an alternative answer to the questions above.
Let's start clean with an $ n $-dimensional oriented Riemannian manifold $ (M,g) $ and an oriented hypersurface $ S\subset M $. I'll denote with $ \iota\colon S\hookrightarrow M $ the canonical inclusion mapping and with $ \hat N $ be the outward pointing unit normal vector along $ S $.
The ancillary questions
First of all I want to address my Ancillary Question No. 2. The following statement is true:

Theorem. Let $ \vec G $ be a vector field on $ M $ [1]. Let $ \alpha = \star(\vec G^\flat) $ be the $ (n - 1) $-form on $ M $ induced by $ \vec G $. Then
$$
\int_S\iota^*\alpha = \int_S\langle\vec G,\hat N\rangle_g\eta_g
$$
where $ \eta_g $ is the volume form on $ S $ induced by the pullback metric $ \iota^*g $.

This fact is an immediate consequence of following lemma, the proof of which can be found among the pages of Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" [2].

Theorem. Let $ \vec G $ and $ \alpha $ as in the theorem above. Then
$$
\iota^*\alpha = \langle\vec G,\hat N\rangle_g\eta_g\,\text{.}
$$

All of this is basically irrelevant for the following.
Proof of the main formula
First of all notice that given a vector field $ \vec G $ on $ M $ then
$$
\star(\vec G^\flat) = \vec G\mathop{\lrcorner} \omega_g
$$
where $ \omega_g $ is the Riemannian volume on $ M $ induced by the metric.
Suppose now that $ M = \mathbb R^n $ and $ g = \delta $ (i.e. the Euclidean flat metric). I'll denote with $ \{e_1,\dots,e_n\} $ the canonical global orthonormal frame field on the manifold $ M $ and with $ \{f^1,\dots,f^{n - 1}\} $ the canonical frame of the "coordinate space" $ \mathbb R^{n - 1} $.
It helps to consider a parametrization $ \gamma\colon V\to S $ of $ S $ defined on an open set $ V\subset \mathbb R^{n - 1} $. In the following I'll suppose for simplicity that $ \operatorname{supp}{\vec G}\subset \gamma(V) $.
Then
$$
\int_S\alpha = \int_S\iota^*(\vec G\mathop{\lrcorner}\omega_g) = \int_V \gamma^*\iota^*(\vec G\mathop{\lrcorner}\omega_g)
$$
so in order to obtain an explicit coordinate formula we need to express the last integrand as
$$
\gamma^*\iota^*(\vec G\mathop{\lrcorner}\omega_g) = h\, f^1\wedge\dots\wedge f^{n - 1}
$$
for some smooth function $ h $ defined on $ S $. Only then we could write $ \int_S\alpha $ as an ordinary (Lebesgue) integral
$$
\int_S\alpha = \int_V h(q)\,\lambda^{n -1}(\mathrm dq)
$$
of a real valued function, where $ \lambda^{n - 1} $ is the $ (n - 1) $-dimensional Lebesgue measure on the Euclidean $ (n - 1) $-dimensional space.
Using the fact that
$$
\omega_g = e^1\wedge\dots\wedge e^n
$$
we will have
$$
h(q) = \left\langle{\gamma^*\iota^*(\vec G\mathop{\lrcorner}\omega_g)\rvert_q,f_1\wedge\dots\wedge f_{n - 1}}\right\rangle = \left\langle{e^1\wedge\dots\wedge e^n,\vec G(q)\wedge \frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial q^1}(q)\wedge\dots \wedge \frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial q^{n - 1}}(q)}\right\rangle
$$
for every $ q\in V $, i.e.,
$$
h(q) =
\begin{vmatrix}
G^1(\gamma(q)) & \frac{\partial\gamma^1}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots & \frac{\partial\gamma^1}{\partial q^{n - 1}}(q)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
G^n(\gamma(q)) & \frac{\partial\gamma^n}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots & \frac{\partial\gamma^n}{\partial q^{n - 1}}(q)
\end{vmatrix}\,\text{.}
$$
We can now integrate! By definition
$$
\int_S\alpha = \int_V h(q)\,\lambda^{n - 1}(\mathrm dq) = \int_V {\begin{vmatrix}
G^1(\gamma(q)) & \frac{\partial\gamma^1}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots & \frac{\partial\gamma^1}{\partial q^{n - 1}}(q)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
G^n(\gamma(q)) & \frac{\partial\gamma^n}{\partial q^1}(q) & \cdots & \frac{\partial\gamma^n}{\partial q^{n - 1}}(q)
\end{vmatrix}}\,\lambda^{n - 1}(\mathrm dq)
$$
which is exactly the formula we were trying to obtain.
Some comments on $ n = 3 $
In multivariable calculus the quantity
$$
\Phi_S(\vec G) = \int_V{\left(\vec G(\gamma(x,y))\cdot \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x}(x,y)\times \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)}\,\underbrace{\lambda^1(\mathrm dx)\otimes \lambda^1(\mathrm dy)}_{\text{the product measure}}
$$
is called the flux of the vector field $ \vec G $ through $ S $. As before $ \gamma $ is some parametrization of $ S $ and I am assuming that $ \operatorname{supp}{\vec G}\subset V $ because I'm scared of partitions of unity.
It's still unclear to me how the integrand
$$
h(x,y) = \overbrace{\vec G(\gamma(x,y))\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x}(x,y)\times \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial y}(x,y)}_{\text{some normal vector to $ S $}}}^{\text{the normal component of $ \vec G $}}\label{integrand}\tag{$*$}
$$
arises. I mean, of course the coordinate expansion of such a scalar product is given by that big determinant above. But I'm not really satisfied with that. First of all because this formula recalls more the
$$
\langle \vec G,\hat N\rangle\eta_g\label{normal}\tag{$**$}
$$
formula above than the
$$
\vec G\mathop{\lrcorner}\omega_g 
$$
we used in proving the determinant formula, and I don't see how to get $ \eqref{integrand} $ from $ \eqref{normal} $ (or better, the Lebesgue integral $ \int_V(*)\mathrm d\lambda^{n - 1} $ directly from the integral of forms $ \int_S(**) $).

[1] More generally $ \vec G $ could be a  vector field along $ S $, i.e., a smooth map $ \vec G\colon S\to \mathrm TM $ such that $ \vec G(p)\in \mathrm T_pM $ for all $ p\in S $.
[2] Proposition 16.30 of the second edition.
